# Efficient way to make a (PHP) redirection functionality for multiple (128) database values

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, hyperlink

Currently I am working on a webpage where certain data from a database is being fetched and displayed to the user. This information is about certain project information and the lead partners of those projects. I want to implement a functionality where the user can click on a lead partner (link) and the link will redirect this user to another page (*where the database information of all the organisations is on*) **BUT** with a **predefined** search for only the organisations that are equal to the clicked lead partner link.

I found a solution on how to do this but the problem is that the solution (which i describe further below) isn't that good/efficient for multiple (128) organisations.. So the question is, do you know a better/more efficient solution to achieve this. To answer this question you probably also need some background information:

**BACKGROUND INFORMATION**

In the outputted database information (which is done in a table) there are several information columns/titles such as:

- Project name
- Organisations involved
- Leader partner
- Project website
  And so on...

The fetching of the data is being done with a simple query where certain database columns have a specific identifier. For example, the project website columns is obviously a link, so in the query it is being done as follows: $SomeQueryVar = ("SELECT project_website as LINK FROM xxxx WHERE project_website ('$some_website') "); -- Just a short example to clarify things.

For the displaying, the data is being 'catched' like so:

```
if(count($SomeQueryVar)>0){
    for($i=0;$i<count($SomeQueryVar);$i++){      
        echo "<tr>";  
        foreach($SomeQueryVar[$i] as $key=>$value){              

            echo "<td>";

            $b=unserialize($value);

            if($key =='LINK' && $value != NULL){ 
                $first = true; 
                array_filter($b); 
                foreach($b as $y){
                    echo '<a href="'.$y.'">'."Project website".'</a>';
                    $first = false;     
                    if(!$first) break;
                }                               
            } else {
                    echo $value;
            }
            echo "</td>";                                                   
        }    
        echo "</tr>";

    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code, certain database columns need other displaying as the rest. For example, links must be clickable instead of just being plain text. These **'exceptions'** are being catched with the **if $key ==**, for the data that just needs regular displaying (plain text) there is the last else inserted that just echo's the $value.

**MY FOUND SOLUTION**

So regarding the question, i found out that i can create redirection links using the ?SomePage on the projects page and using this 'added link value' on the organisations page to compare it. If the link is equal, then do the specific query. But it is probably easier to paste the code here:

**The 'CATCHING' part**
To catch a specific lead partner is also used an identifier in my query called ORG (which stands for organisation). So here is the code where i catch the organisations table:

```
if($key =='ORG' && $value != NULL){ 
    $needle = array('Brainport','Development','BRAINPORT',
                    'brainport','DEVELOPMENT','development');
    $needle2 = array('Casa','CASA', 'casa');
    if (strpos_arr($value,$needle) !== false) {                     
        echo '<a href="http://portal.e-ucare.eu/database/organisations/?a=brainport" >'.$value.'</a>';
    }

    if (strpos_arr($value,$needle2) !== false) {                        
        echo '<a href="http://portal.e-ucare.eu/database/organisations/?a=casa" >'.$value.'</a>';
    }
}
```

In the above code i just created it for 2 organisations (brainport and casa). For this solution i used a function called strpos_arr which searches for the needle in the haystack;) So in the code above i set the needles to the names in the database where it has to create a link for. So if for example a company with the word Brainport exists in the database, this 'catcher' will see this and display the organisation and make the name clickable.

**The strpos_arr function for the $needle is as follows:**

```
function strpos_arr($value, $needle) {
    if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);
    foreach($needle as $what) {
        if(($pos = strpos($value, $what))!==false) return $pos;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the redirection page the code will also catch certain links to make queries for that link -- so for the brainport link this is http://portal.e-ucare.eu/database/organisations/?a=brainport -- in the second page code this link is catched like so:

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'portal.e-ucare.eu/database/organisations/?a=brainport') 
{

    $link_word = "Brainport";
    $tmp = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT
                name_of_company__organization, company_location, 
                company_website as LINK, organisation_type, 
                organisation_active_in_, organisation_scope, 
                organisation_files as DOC           
            FROM           
                wp_participants_database            
            WHERE
                name_of_company__organization REGEXP ('$link_word')
            ORDER BY 
                name_of_company__organization ASC
            ");     
}
```

With this solution i can do what i want, **BUT** like i said in the beginning, i need this for not just 2 organisations but **128!!** This would mean i have to copy the catching code blocks on both pages **128 times!!** This is obviously not very efficient..

So is there any more efficient way to achieve this? Sorry if it is a bit unclear but i found it quite hard to easily wright this down;)

Anyway, thank you in advance!

Comment: if you want redirection you can use php header location function to forward to the url. in order to do that make sure there aren't other output on the page so it forwards correctly. if that's not possible you can use snippets of JavaScript page forward code to start redirection.

Comment: just how much code will be common between each of those 128 blocks? I can't see why you'd need 128 blocks if the only thing changing is a single world, like `brainport`.

Comment: @Marc B Each of these 'words' which represent companies will need their own specific query on the page where the organisations are on, cause if i click a link of organisation A I don't want information about organisation B on my redirection page. So in the catching block i will need 128 different if cond. that check if the needle is that company so it can echo the corresponding link. In addition, the second (redirection to) page needs to check 128 different links to create 128 different queries.

Comment: so why not put the redirect url into the db in a new field? no need for 128 if/else/else/.../else ad-nauseum. just pull the url out from the db along with the other info and do the redirect in a single `If (special url exists) { redirect to it }`

Comment: @Nicolas is it possible to modify your database structure at all? It seems like alot of your desired functionality can be implemented by putting meta data into the database and generating your desired data using joins.

Comment: @Populus sadly enough i am just a rookie, so even if it was possible I would have no clue how to do this. But the database is automatically build on a plugin of WordPress, so no the database cant be modified without losing the plugins functionality sadly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firts part you can rewrite to

```
if($key =='ORG' && $value != NULL){ 
    $needles = array(
                'brainport'=>array('Brainport','Development','BRAINPORT','brainport','DEVELOPMENT','development'),
                'casa'=>array('Casa','CASA', 'casa')
                );
    foreach($needles AS $nkey => $needle){
        if(strpos_arr($value,$needle) !== false) {                     
            echo "<a href='http://portal.e-ucare.eu/database/organisations/?a={$nkey}' >{$value}</a>";
        }
    }
}
```

For the second part make an array like
[EDIT]

```
    $link_words = array(
                'portal.e-ucare.eu/database/organisations/?a=brainport'=>'Brainport',
                'portal.e-ucare.eu/database/organisations/?a=casa'=>'Casa',
            );
```

then you can use

```
    $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(!empty($link_words[$host])){
    $link_word = $link_words[$host];
    $tmp = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT
                name_of_company__organization, company_location, company_website as LINK, organisation_type, organisation_active_in_, organisation_scope, organisation_files as DOC         
            FROM           
                wp_participants_database            
            WHERE
                name_of_company__organization REGEXP ('$link_word')
            ORDER BY 
                name_of_company__organization ASC
        ");     
}
```

Comment: Super, thank you a lot! Exactly what I was looking for. But in your example I would only have to add the 128 companies in the links_word array? So I will have 128 arrays? Anyway this is much and much less work so thank you!